# PHP redirect to a page with Data

Tags: php, header

Ok so i have a from that people are using on our site to download a software application....There are actually 4 different forms that are linking to the same php script and i need to redirect all of them to the thank_you page with the $_POST['application_to_download'] the problem i am having is how do i send this variable with the php header..here is my code

this will just open the download

```
header("location:".$_POST['application_to_download']);
```

which works great but i need the user to be redirected to the thank_you page...so my second approach was to try the post approach

```
$post_data = "software={$_POST['application_to_download']}";
$content_length = strlen($post_data);

header('POST /downloads/thank_you HTTP/1.1');
header('Host: localhost');
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
header('Content-length: ' . $content_length);
header('');
header($post_data);
```

Im not sure whats going on with this approach but its just not redirecting at all and lastly i can do this

```
header("location:"./downloads/thank_you?software=$_POST['application_to_download']);
```

something like that but the url looks like this

```
 http://somesite.com/downloads/thank_you?software=videovision10_1_07.exe
```

which is not the prettiest if you ask me....i mean i know i can do this but i was looking for an alternative....btw here is why i need it on the thank_you page

```
<title>Thank You</title>
</head>
<body onload="window.location = '<?php print $_POST['software']; ?>'">
```

any suggestions

Comment: You are confusing *request headers* with *response headers* - that's why you can't post with the Location redirect.

Comment: POST is client->server. The way you're setting your headers, you're trying to POST from server->client, which is not possible, as Renesis says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend instead that you redirect to the thank-you page, and use a meta-refresh to trigger the file download.

```
header('Location: /thank_you_page.php?redirectTo=' . $_POST['app_to_dl']);
```

and in the thank you page:

```
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"REFRESH\" CONTENT=\"1;URL=" . $_GET['redirectTo'] . "\">";
```

Give that a shot..

edit: Now I see you mentioned the GET variable... Do you really think people are looking at your URL and judging it?

Answer (score 1):

For every *request* that a browser makes, you have **one** *response* that you can make.  You want to display a thank you page.  So that uses up the one.  That means that the Thank You page has to automatically trigger the browser to make a *second* request.

Your options are a Javascript refresh:

```
window.onload = function() {
    location.href = '<?php echo $app; ?>';
}
```

Or a HTTP Meta refresh (this one shows you how to wait 1 second):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;<?php echo $app; ?>">
```

For that page to know what `$app` is, and embed it into the page, you have two options:

1. URL (GET) - which you have the code for (and say is ugly)
2. Session

   ```
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['app'] = $_POST['application_to_download'];
   ```

   ...

   ```
   $app = $_SESSION['app'];
   unset($_SESSION['app']);
   ```